# How to create a string of properties in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to to make a string which includes custom props in react native .Following is the code

```
arr.push({url:require(images[i].path) });
```

I can make a string of type url:'paths' in react native , but I also want

> require

to be a part of it. How to make such a string ?

Comment: `require` accept only **string literals**

Comment: yes, so how to make an object of that type ? so that it evaluates include function ?

Comment: do you want to make object of your local images?

Comment: @Pritish you image paths are predefined at compile time ? or they will only be known at run-time ?

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli run time, that is the issue

Comment: @Nirmalsinh images are local, but another picker library choses it at run time

Comment: @Pritish then there's no way you could use variable inside `require` statement, but .. why are pushing the image itself (by calling `require`) into your array ? .. what's the purpose of that array you're composing ?

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli requirement is lt user select multiple pic of his own and show it in gallery

Comment: @Pritish then you only need to store the `uri` of your image ... `require` is only needed for rendering

Comment: @Pritish if you could share the code that makes use of this `arr` .. it'd be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

require does not support dynamic imports. So the solution for you is put result of require to array

```
const images = [
  require('some_path1'), 
  require('some_path2'), 
  ..., 
  require('some_pathN')
]
```

then

```
arr.push({url: images[i]});
```